# Work with more than 300 test cases at once in TestLink

Tags: testlink

I have a project with more than 3500 test cases and I want to create a few executions with a test assignment for testers. Unfortunately, if I try to operate with more than 300 test cases at once, I encounter problems:

1. If I try to add ~900 test cases in execution then I see "DB access error";
2. If I try to add ~300 test cases to execution, then there is no error message, but only ~80% of highlighted test cases are really added to the execution;
3. If I try to assign >300 tests for testers then, like in the previous case, only ~80% of highlighted tests are really assigned to testers.

Is there a workaround for these problems or I can't use TestLink and I need to migrate to a non-free product?

Comment: This sound like a support issue for TestLink.  You should probably contact Teamtest @ http://testlink.org and report this as an issue.  I would first recommend you search their online help.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Firstly I thought that someone from community may already have an answer :)
Anyway, here is an issue in TestLink's Mantis: http://mantis.testlink.org/view.php?id=8137

Comment: Good find & glad to help!-)  I have worked on dev tools in the past and we were always grateful for hearing about stuff like this.